# Node.jsで(同ドメインの)LocalStrageを取得する方法

Tags: node.js

AngularJSとNode.jsを併用しているWEBアプリを作成しています。
AngularJS側で保存したLocalStrageの値をNode.js側で取得したいです。
(JSだとwindow.localStrage()で取得できるもの)

Node.js側ではどうすれば取得できますでしょうか？

＊JavaScriptのwindow.localStrageではエラーとなり取得できませんでした。
＊node-localstorageというパッケージを使ってみましたが開発環境のディレクトリ一覧が取得できたので
　そもそも取得できる場所が違いますかね？

ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授願います。
(他サイトでも同様の質問を投げてます。)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LocalStorage は Cookie などと同じくクライアント＝ブラウザ側で記憶されるものです。また Cookie と違い、自動的にサーバーへ送信されることはありません。

ですから、 Node.js であろうと「サーバー側から LocalStorage の値を読みだす」ことはできません。

LocalStorage からデータを取り出してサーバーに送る、といった処理をブラウザ側の Javascript で実装する必要があります。

Comment: Node.jsもサーバー側で処理させる言語ですし、そうなりますよね・・・
考えが足りませんでした・・・

回答ありがとうございました！